# Interpreting Javascript from Python

Tags: javascript, python, interpreter

I want to be able to interpret or compile Javascript files, catching errors, etc. from Python programs. Javascript Files use the following syntax for ex.:

```
var a;
function Mul (){
  prompt(b);
  document.write(a*b);
}
```

I tried with SpiderMonkey but it seems to be unable to interpret "prompt", "document.write", etc. Help please.

Comment: Can u plz tell me which standard of EMACS is that uses prompt and document.write ?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, mate.

Comment: Why?! Plz help. I'm really stack and have no time.

Comment: so you want to check `.js` file ???

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want to Check, interpret or compile JS Files within Python Programs.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10136319/205528

Comment: Dikei, this may be what I'm looking for. I'm gonna read it and try it. Hope works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Javascript function from Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284765/call-javascript-function-from-python)

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like `document.write` can't work since SpiderMonkey is not a browser. So there's no document, and no DOM. Likewise, you don't have a window, so no alerts or prompts. All this wouldn't make much sense in a command-line script...

You could build your own DOM parser in Python (assuming you actually have a web page to parse in the first place), and create a `document` object yourself, but that would probably be a lot of work for very little return.