# Execute Javascript method on web page from Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am writing a web scraper for a particular webpage and I am doing this with "urllib2.Request(MyURL)" and "BeautifulSoup" but the problem is that there is a Paging on page in MyURL and the next page loads (in same myURL/page) by clicking on a link, behind this link is the javascript method written as

```
{ javascript:__doPostBack('rptPagingBottom$ctl01$btnPage','') }.
```

Now without executing this Javascript function from Python, I can not get a complete page listing. How can I call this Javascript method from Python so that I can get all pages of that web page?

I found one related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284765/call-javascript-function-from-python) where it is suggested to use (Rhino, V8, SeaMonkey) but I did not get this at all. I need some example code if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this kind of dirty work(inline js, ajax page loading). It is able to emulate exact what browsers can do with python and browser-driver.

You can get some info about how to use it as a crawler by search google with keyword 'selenium crawler'.