# Run python from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, iot, pyv8

I have implemented an accelerometer Reader in python and I want to execute a function in a javascript file when a new value is read that will:
1 - update the value in a database
2 - broadcast the new value to all connected client ( via Socket.io)

I was wondering how to do it? I checked PyV8 but it seems not maintained and only working with Python 2.7.
My files structure looks like

```
--JScode
----MyJSCode
--PythonCode
----MyPythonCode
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call a Javascript function from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284765/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-python)

Comment: Sounds like an awful headache, but you may be able to get something working with pyqt

Comment: Can you use Node.js and call the node binary from Python? That's easier than evoking a script in a web browser binary

Comment: Actually I'm already using Node.js, my web app is build as a MEAN (Mongo Express Angular Node). can you give me a link to how to do it with the node binary ? thanks

Comment: You can send messages between processes using *pipes*. Just have your node server listen for a message and have your Python program send them.

Comment: Have you tried Js2Py? https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py

Comment: Yes, but from what I understood it's not possible to run a function located in another file with js2Py, all it does is just interpret function passed as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to execute a python script from the javascript file using `PythonShell` ([link to the npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell))