# run a javascript function inside a python

Tags: javascript, python, django, string, django-templates

I'm working on a project. I have a `strings.py` which has `dicts` like below:

```
def bar(self):
    #do something


STRINGS_ENGLISH = {
     'title': 'foo'
     'function': bar
}
```

then I wanna use this string in my Django template, I'll pass it through my context in the template named `string`.

**I know that If I wanna print the `title` in the HTML it's enough to write `{{strings.title}}`,**

but about the function I want to pass it to a button like that:

```
<button onclick="{function()}">Do Something</button>
```

but it's a python function! not a js function. so what should I do?

Comment: Is Python powering your back-end, JavaScript front? You wouldn't typically need to mix python with JavaScript, what would be the benefit? If it's a back-end application, then your logic *should* be separated. It is possible however, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284765/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-python is almost the answer you're looking for.

Comment: you cannot call a python function because django is backend and javascript is frontend. You need to look into XMLHttpRequests to do what you want to do.

Comment: yes I know, I try to use javascript just for my Django-template. the benefit of this string collection is the harmony that the strings of a template file give me. I load all of my data from a string file and now I try to load also functions from my strings file